# PowerShell script that reassigns users licenses with MS Graph throws 401 Authentication error despite API permissions on Enterprise App

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

first time posting here, hopefully I am in the right place with this question.

I have a script that I am working on that will check if users in a csv file have a Microsoft 365 E3 license and if so, remove it and assign a M365 F3 license. I have created an app in Azure and have granted admin consent to the following permissions

```
LicenseAssignment.ReadWrite.All
Organization.ReadWrite.All
User.ReadWrite.All
```

Here is the script

```
#Configuration
$ClientId = REDACTED
$TenantId = REDACTED
$CertificateThumbprint = REDACTED

#Connect to Microsoft Graph with CBA
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $ClientId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint

#Path to the CSV file containing user information
$csvPath = "C:\Users\TestUser\Users.csv"

#Import the CSV file
$userList = Import-Csv $csvPath

#Loop through each user in the CSV
foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    try {
        # Query user information from Microsoft Graph using Invoke-RestMethod
        $graphUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userPrincipalName"
        $userDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphUri -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $($AccessToken)"
            'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
            'Accept'        = 'application/json;odata.metadata=full'
        }

        #Extract license details from the user details
        $userLicense = $userDetails.licenses | Where-Object { $_.skuId -eq "SPE_E3" -or $_.skuId -eq "SPE_F1" }

        #Check if the user has an E3 license
        if ($userLicense -and $userLicense.skuId -eq "SPE_E3") {
            # Remove E3 license and assign F3 license
            Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $userPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "SPE_E3" -AddLicenses "SPE_F1"
        } elseif ($userLicense -and $userLicense.skuId -eq "SPE_F1") {
            # User already has an F3 license, do nothing
        } else {
            # Handle other license types if necessary
        }
    } catch {
        # Handle errors if needed
        Write-Host "Error processing user $($userPrincipalName): $_"
    }
}
```

I receive this output for each test user in the csv file

`Error processing user Intune.TestUser@mydomain.com: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

Initially I tried using this command to connect to MS Graph

`Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.ReadWrite.All, LicenseAssignment.ReadWrite.All`

I had the same results with the 401 error which prompted me to create the Azure app. Note I am using ISE to test all of this. I have ensured the MS Graph module was up to date and have tried disconnecting from graph to ensure there were no hung sessions

Comment: are you including the ClientId and Cert in the `-Scopes` call?

Comment: Hi, Yes I believe I have that covered here:                                                            ```#Connect to Microsoft Graph with CBA
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $ClientId -TenantId $TenantId -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint```                                          Initially I was using a different command to connect to MS Graph but i went with the above method after creating the Azure app

Comment: I don't see `-Scopes` in that line